# How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, call, masm

To make a normal (near direct relative) `call` to an absolute address, in NASM or AT&T syntax you write `call 0x1234567`, and the assembler + linker take care of calculating a `rel32` to reach that target from wherever the linker puts the `call` instruction.

e.g. on Linux assembling that into a static 64-bit ELF executable with `yasm -felf64 foo.asm && ld foo.o -o foo`, then disassembled with `objdump -drwC -Mintel foo` gives you:

```
foo:     file format elf64-x86-64
Disassembly of section .text:
0000000000400080 <_start>:
  400080:       e8 e2 44 e3 00          call   1234567 <_end+0xc344df>
```

The linker calculated the right rel32 to reach `0x1234567` from `0x400080+5`, based on a `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation in the object file:

```
  0:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   5 <_start+0x5>   1: R_X86_64_PC32        *ABS*+0x1234563
```

---

**How do you get MASM and/or MSVC inline-asm to do that?**

MSVC doesn't accept  `_asm { call 1234567h; }`.  The error is  `C2415: improper operand type`.  [The only SO answer I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933143/immediate-call-jmp-in-visual-c-inline-assembler) suggests using a workaround of an indirect jmp with the address in memory or a register, but making inefficient machine code because of hard-to-use tools isn't a very good solution.

I don't have MASM at all, so I've only been able to try MSVC inline-asm (which is not the same thing) [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+foo()+%7B%0A+++//__asm+__emit++0xe8%0A+++//__asm+__emit++(0x00405B90+-+$)%0A%0A+++_asm+%0A+++%7B%0A++++++call+0x00405B90%0A+++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),header:(),k:49.534686971235196,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cl19_32,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Ox',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.465313028764804,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:4,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%234+with+x86+MSVC+19+2017+RTW',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.465313028764804,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

Can you set the address of a label and use it as a target for `call symbol`?  Like with GAS's `.set symbol, 0x1234567` which lets you give a symbol an address *without* having to actually writing `symbol:` anywhere.

Can you emit the encoding directly with `db 0E8h` / `dd 1234567h - ($ + 4)`?  Probably not, [in NASM that only works with `label - $`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly), not `absolute - label`

---

I'm mostly interested in the answer so I can include it in my canonical answer about jmp/call to an absolute address: [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code)  Definitely not for any code I want to actually use.

Comment: I just tested this again on GNU/Linux (for [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071606/why-is-my-branch-instruction-not-jumping-to-the-given-address)), and it only works properly with YASM, not NASM.  NASM treats `je 0x123` as if a default `org` setting applied even though none is given, so it doesn't even put a relocation entry in the `.o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MASM doesn't support this because the COFF object file format doesn't support the necessary relocation.  (Or doesn't *correctly* support it? According to a NASM error message.)

Using the `call 0x76cd75c0` syntax in `nasm -f win32` gives an error:

```
error: Win32 COFF does not correctly support relative references to absolute addresses
```

I don't know if MASM targeting real mode flat binaries could do it (where there are no object files that have to describe the relocations to the linker), but probably MASM was just designed without syntax for it at all, unfortunately.

---

See also [Error when calling function in user32.dll directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53461451/error-when-calling-function-in-user32-dll-directly).  I did try `nasm -fwin32` 2.13.02 myself on my Linux desktop and got the same error.

---

**An untested *possible* workaround** might be to create a `.obj` with a symbol definition for that absolute address, like

```
org 0deadbeefH
global my_target
my_target:
```

in NASM or however you do that in MASM.

Then in MASM or MSVC inline-asm you can use `jmp my_target` and link with that `.obj`.  In theory that might work around the problem of representing relocations in the object file, and get the linker to calculate the relative branch displacement.