# Get informations from decompiled ASM

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, calling-convention, ghidra

I am willing to modify camera coordinate on a little 3D game. I have been able to find three functions, one for each axes.
Let's call them CameraX, CameraY and CameraZ. I have been working only with the first one, when I found out that I was missing something.

Here are ASM instructions, got from Ghidra :

```
                             *************************************************************
                             *                           FUNCTION                         
                             *************************************************************
                             undefined1  __register  CameraX (undefined2  x)
             undefined1        AL:1           <RETURN>
             undefined2        AX:2           x
             undefined1        Stack[-0x14]   local_14                                XREF[8]:     00478abe (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478aca (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478b44 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478b53 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478bb3 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478bbf (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478c1d (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478c29 (*)   
             undefined4        Stack[-0x18]   local_18                                XREF[4]:     00478ae8 (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478b6e (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478bdd (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478c47 (R)   
             undefined4        Stack[-0x1c]   local_1c                                XREF[4]:     00478ae1 (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478b67 (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478bd6 (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478c40 (R)   
             undefined4        Stack[-0x20]   local_20                                XREF[8]:     00478ace (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478ada (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478b57 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478b60 (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478bc3 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478bcf (R) , 
                                                                                                   00478c2d (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478c39 (R)   
             undefined8        Stack[-0x28]   local_28                                XREF[4,2]:   004789ec (*) , 
                                                                                                   004789f5 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478b06 (*) , 
                                                                                                   00478b0f (*) , 
                                                                                                   004789f1 (W) , 
                                                                                                   00478b0b (W)   
             undefined4        Stack[-0x2c]   local_2c                                XREF[1]:     00478b40 (*)   
                             CameraX                                         XREF[1]:     FUN_0047a280:0047a291 (c)   
        004789e0 53              PUSH       EBX
        004789e1 56              PUSH       ESI
        004789e2 83  c4  e0       ADD        ESP ,-0x20
        004789e5 8b  f0           MOV        ESI ,x
        004789e7 e8  68  9b       CALL       FUN_00462554                                     undefined FUN_00462554()
                 fe  ff
        004789ec 89  04  24       MOV        dword ptr [ESP ]=> local_28 ,x
        004789ef 33  c0           XOR        x,x
        004789f1 89  44  24       MOV        dword ptr [ESP  + local_28 +0x4 ],x
                 04
        004789f5 df  2c  24       FILD       qword ptr [ESP ]=> local_28
        004789f8 dc  66  08       FSUB       qword ptr [ESI  + 0x8 ]
        004789fb d9  1d  18       FSTP       dword ptr [DAT_00871218 ]                        = ??
                 12  87  00


...
...
...


        00478c4e 8b  c3          MOV        x,EBX
        00478c50 83  c4  20      ADD        ESP ,0x20
        00478c53 5e              POP        ESI
        00478c54 5b              POP        EBX
        00478c55 c3              RET
```

I know that :
- My executable is 32 bits, made in Delphi.
- x is the new x-axis value.

My goal is to use this function with an injected dll. I came to this :

```cpp
typedef int (__stdcall *_CameraX)(int x);
_CameraX CameraX = (_CameraX)0x04789E0;
```

But no way, I am having an "access violation" on the line `004789fb FSTP dword ptr [DAT_00871218]`. This is the first use of x value. So I guess it is the wrong type.

Here is what I understood :
- Since the original program is written in Delphi, __pascal calling convention came in mind. Since it is deprecated in Visual studio, I am using __stdcall. I assume that, since there is only one argument* it would not make any difference.
- x was always a large number. I would have picked long if it was not in 32 bits.
- I don't really know for the return type. I picked int because the caller function make a `test al, al` just after the call.

* : Ghidra is telling me there is only one argument, but if I was listening to myself, there would be 2 :

```
        004789e0 53              PUSH       EBX
        004789e1 56              PUSH       ESI
...
...
        00478c53 5e              POP        ESI
        00478c54 5b              POP        EBX
        00478c55 c3              RET
```

So here are my questions :
- Is there really only one argument ?
- Which calling convention should I use if the right one is __pascal, since it is unusable with Visual Studio ? (If there is more than one argument)
- What is the way to retrieve the return value ?
- Why have we "invented" so many calling convention ? Why don't we all use __cdecl, for example ? Why some use Right to Left, when some others read from Left to Right ? Is there any differences ?

I am pretty sure that some informations are lacking, would the pseudocode generated by Ghidra be usefull ?

Edit :

```c
int CameraX(int x)

{
  undefined4 *puVar1;
  uint uVar2;
  undefined4 unaff_EBX;
  int iVar3;
  float10 in_ST0;
  undefined4 local_20;
  undefined4 local_1c;
  undefined4 local_18;
  undefined local_14 [12];

  uVar2 = FUN_00462554();
  DAT_00871218 = (float)(ulonglong)uVar2 - (float)*(double *)(x + 8);
    iVar3 = CONCAT31((int3)((uint)unaff_EBX >> 8),1);
  if (*(float *)(x + 0x6c) < DAT_00871218) {
  // ...
```

Edit 2 :

Here is the complete ASM code :
https://pastebin.com/UiGGEju1
and here is Ghidra generated pseudo code :
https://pastebin.com/1Fc48k1g

so I guess I was wrong : it wasn't the line I thought that was causing this issue but this one : `00478c3d   89 46 1c  MOV dword ptr [ESI + 0x1c],x`
but it's still my x value that is causing it.

What I don't understand is "why" : x is an int (32 bits) and the program is trying to store it as a dword (32 bits) in [ESI + 0x1c]. Is it possible that the program could not resolve where/what is x ? (like if I was calling the function with no argument)

By the way this question : "- Why have we "invented" so many calling convention ? Why don't we all use __cdecl, for example ? Why some use Right to Left, when some others read from Left to Right ? Is there any differences ?"
has not been answered and really intrigue me, if you have the explication, I would be glad to listen to it !

Comment: You can't really have the fault at that line as that is just writing to global storage which should work. The code seems to use a nonstandard calling sequence since the argument is passed in `eax`. Also that seems to be passed on to `FUN_00462554` via `esi`.

Comment: Why did you decide that this is pascal calling convention? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @interjay: "Based on the Borland Pascal programming language's calling convention, the parameters are pushed on the stack in left-to-right order (opposite of cdecl), and the callee is responsible for removing them from the stack." (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), it sounded to me like it was it, could you please tell me which point is wrong in this sentence ?
Jester: I am clearly having a popup saying "Access violation on address "004789fb"". I would like to show you Ghidra pseudocode for this line (see the last paragraph of the above topic.

Comment: @Nox You're just saying what the pascal calling convention is. But this is not the calling convention used by this assembly code.

Comment: @Jester: How do you know it is past by ``eax`` ?

Comment: @interjay: Can you please tell me if my thinking is right ? - Callee save the stack (004789e0) - Callee clean the stack (00478c54) - I don't know for the reading-convention, but since there is (apparently) one argument, it doesn't matter. So I can use __stdcall. Note that Jester said : "The code seems to use a nonstandard calling sequence since the argument is passed in eax" and the above wikipedia page tells us : "Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are designated for use within the function. Return values are stored in the EAX register. "

Comment: Your decompiler says so itself: `undefined2 AX:2 x` and later you can see `004789e5 8b  f0 MOV ESI ,x` which is `mov esi, eax` and `eax` has not been set to anything hence its value must be coming from the caller.

Comment: This is not pascal or stdcall because those pass values through stack and this uses registers. You have to use a compatible calling convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like it's using the **Borland register calling** convention (also known as **Borland `fastcall`**):

- It takes `EAX`, `EDX` then `ECX` as first three parameters, respectively;
- The 4th and up arguments go in the stack;
- The callee must preserve the `EBX`, `ESI`, `EDI`, and `EBP` registers;
- `EAX` is used as a return method for 32-bit integers;
- ...and some other rules that don't apply here.

You can see your function saves the `EBX` and `ESI` registers and also does not use `EDI` nor `EBP`. It also uses `EAX` as the first parameter `x` and returns the result in `EAX` also, as per convention.

There's no equivalent calling convention for Borland `fastcall` in modern Visual Studio. You'll probably rely on using inline assembly as a workaround on calling this Delphi function.

This workaround would probably work using a temporary Microsoft `fastcall` function pointer as it also uses registers for the first parameters, except for `EAX`, which we'll have to pass using inline assembly, something like (not sure of the code syntax, treat it as pseudo-code):

```c++
typedef void (__fastcall *_CameraX)();
_CameraX CameraXTemp = (_CameraX)0x04789E0;

int CameraX(int x) {
    int ret;
    __asm mov eax, x
    CameraXTemp();
    __asm mov ret, eax
    return ret;
}
```

Note that if this method works, you're gonna need to invert the next two parameters (for functions with 2 or 3 arguments), because Microsoft's `fastcall` expects `ECX` then `EDX` in that order. For 4 or more arguments, I assume some stack work would be needed.

Another approach would be to use a *naked* function, I assume it would look something like this:

```c++
__declspec(naked) int __stdcall CameraX(int x)
{
    __asm
   {
       mov  eax, [esp + 4] // x
       push ebx
       mov  ebx, 0x04789E0
       call ebx
       pop  ebx
       ret  4 // 1 argument in this __stdcall function (1 * 4)
   }
}
```

For future purposes, if you use this method with another function with more than 1 argument, you'll need to use `RET n` where `n` is `number of arguments * 4`. For 3 arguments or more, you'll also have to push the arguments into the stack like with the former method.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help ! So I tested the first approach : It compiles without any problem, but I am still getting the  "Access violation at address 00478C3D in module '...'. Write of address 004789FC." it is the same message that I already got. (please, see my edit). I tried the second one. I couldn't compile with "call 0x04789E0", so I tried by sending the address through argument. It compiles but give me the same message (with different adresses, out of scope, so I did something wrong)

Comment: The error line means it's trying to write into `[ESI + 0x1C]`, i.e. `[0x004789E0 - 0x1C]`, which is `0x004789FC‬` (what the error says), `ESI` is holding the start of the original `CameraX` function somehow. Looking at the disassembled function, `ESI` is traced back to the value of the argument `x`, which means you're passing the address of the function to the first function argument itself. This also means that `X` (`EAX`) probably is not what you think it is. It looks like a pointer in the context of the original function.

Comment: `__stdcall` is a caller-pops convention (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019).  You need `ret 4` to clear your arg from the stack after the register-arg function returns.  Also, MSVC inline asm unfortunately doesn't support assembling a relative `call` to an absolute target address; you need to do something clunky like putting the absolute address in a register and doing `call ecx`  [How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50058523) (ping @Nox)

Comment: I have been trying a lot of things with the first method, after checking that I was not wrong about the purpose of x. I still don't have his type (I tried int, *int, and to send a function pointer to an int function with no args). No success. Still, I am sure of what is x supposed to do (I have been able to check it through Cheat engine). Any clues on how to find the type of x ? By the way, why do we `ret 4` instead of `ret 1` ? Do we return the number of bytes ?

Comment: Now your stdcall function is broken because it clobbers EBX without saving.  Probably push/pop it around the call.  `push 0x04789E0` / `call [esp]` (and `pop ecx` cleanup) is another option