# Creating relative address references - Rust

Tags: c, assembly, rust, x86, inline-assembly

In code C we can have the following snippet to create a reference to a relative address in memory.

```
int *value = (int*)0x0061FF0C;
```

Since I haven't found a C-like way, I used inline assembly to get the value, but it's just the value, not the reference.

```
unsafe fn read_from_adress(adress:u32) -> i32 {
   let mut data = 0;
   asm!{
       "mov {}, [{}]", 
       out(reg) data,
       in(reg) adress, 
   };
   return data;
}


let var: i32 = read_from_adress(0x0061FF0C);
```

In rust I can't find an equivalent and simple way as in C.

I tried this snippet and to no avail.

```
let value = &mut 0x0061FF0C;
```

Is there a way equivalent to C ?

**obs:** Getting relative address values is being done with dll injection. In both C and Rust

Comment: This is not what "relative" means.

Comment: What I mean by "relative" is about a program's memory locations. So it would be something like: module_base_address + address = relative_address, as this is not the absolute address in memory.

Maybe I'm not expressing myself correctly. But is this the idea of a relative address?

Comment: Dereferencing `0x0061FF0C` as an `(int*)` is in no way relative to the module base address. It is an absolute address. On modern x86 the 32- or 64-bit address is generally an offset, used in the (obsolete) segmentation scheme to yield a linear virtual address, which is then paged to gain a physical address. (Most selectors will be set up to point to flat 4 GiB or 16 EiB segments starting at address zero on modern systems so the offset equals the linear address.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But then for understanding purposes.
I get the base address of a program's module and do
"module_base_address" + "offset(0x0061FF0C)" = address_in_memory_program.
Would that still be an absolute address?
Because what I do when using "0x0061FF0C" is do module_base(0) + "0x0061FF0C"
The base address is 0 because it was dll injection.

Comment: If you use `0x0061FF0C` as a displacement from a module base address then the number is relative, the result is absolute. However, generally no module can have a base address of zero so if you're adding zero then the number is used effectively as an absolute address.

Comment: Are you asking how to get Rust to use a RIP-relative address in 64-bit code to reach a known constant absolute address from wherever the linker puts your code?  Like in [How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50058523) which shows how to do it in YASM syntax for a jump.  In GAS syntax (like Rust inline asm), you might use `mov eax, [rip + 0x0061FF0C - next_instruction]`, where `next_instruction:` is a label right after the `mov` load.  Should be possible to write that with `{}` placeholders for Rust to fill in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and it seems to me to be the light of what I want to understand. Because about the address 0x0061FF0C being absolute is making me confused. For example, if I run 2 programs simultaneously and access their address spaces, I could use the same "relative address" (0x0061FF0C) in both to get the value of a variable. Maybe what I'm saying is about -Virtual Address Space: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/memory/virtual-address-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent Rust code of your C code is:

```rust
let value = unsafe { *(0x0061FF0C as *const i32) };
```

However, as noted in the comments, the address is not relative but absolute.

Comment: I made this modification so that I could create a reference to the address and change the value later. I hope it's correct, but it works.
"let mut value = unsafe { (0x0061FF0C as *mut i32) }; "
*value = 2;

Comment: @RicardoSpinola Yes, it is correct.