# Error when calling function in user32.dll directly

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I read an article some time ago from a guy who demonstrated how one can directly call a function in user32.dll in assembly (NASM) by its memory address. I do not have the article anymore but I'm trying to reproduce the experiment.

The function I want to execute is MessageBoxA in user32.dll and on my computer, the function should be located at the address 0x76cd75c0.

Here is the function:

```
int MessageBoxA(
     HWND hWnd,              # NULL
     LPCSTR IpText,          # text
     LPCSTR IpCaption,       # title
     UINT uType              # style
);
```

Here is the program:

```
global _main                        

section .data                       
msgText:    db 'Hello World', 0
msgCaption: db 'Title', 0       

section .text                   
_main:                          
    push 0
    push msgCaption
    push msgText
    push 0
    call 0x76cd75c0

    add esp, 4
    ret 0x10
```

For compiling the program I use:

```
nasm –f win32 message_box.asm
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
error: Win32 COFF does not correctly support relative references to absolute 
addresses
```

It doesn't matter if I use the normal address or the relative address, I receive the same error message anyway.

Anybody who knows what's the problem?

Comment: This looks like an overly complicated way of using the Win32 API. Why don't you use Hutch's MASM32 package? Its include and library files, and using `invoke`, make accessing the Win32 API very comfortable. And if you like to stick with open software, try the MASM-compatible `JWASM`.

Comment: Yes, it's the point :) Else I would have used _MessageBoxA@16. It's purely experimental, would be kind of cool if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it doesn't exists a `call` that is direct (the address is given directly as an operand), near (no segment) and absolute.
See [here](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html).

`call XXX` is near and direct, so it cannot be absolute.
In fact, it is relative.
NASM [tries to create a relocation](https://github.com/letolabs/nasm/blob/fd8a7ae7edd4d711586dd9399aaf7c0fd7d38a5c/output/outcoff.c#L641) for relative calls (note the `OUT_REL4ADR` type) but `0x76cd75c0` is outside any section defined in the source and apparently this is not supported.

The only way to call a function with an absolute address is by using a `FAR` call, but that requires an immediate segment value.
This rarely ends well in protected mode and a was noted in the comments, that would push `cs` too.
(Otherwise you could use the [0x23 selector that Windows sets for 32-bit applications](http://esec-lab.sogeti.com/posts/2016/09/12/deep-dive-wow64.html) as in `call 0x23:0x76cd75c0`).

You can use an indirect call:

```
mov ebx, 0x76cd75c0
call ebx
```

---

Note that `add esp, 4` looks very wrong here, the Win APIs follow the `stdcall` calling convetion (they clear the stack themselves).

Comment: `call 0x23:0x76cd75c0` will be a lot slower, and will push CS:EIP.  If the function looks for any args on the stack, it will get CS as the first arg.  `mov eax, 0x76cd75c0` / `call eax` should be a lot better.  Or use the normal DLL mechanism of calling through a pointer in memory.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Linux/ELF position-dependent code can use relative calls to reach absolute addresses; I don't know why Windows would omit that and force asm to be inefficient.  But at least that explains why there's no answer to [How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50058523)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point about the far call, better remove that.

Comment: I have already tried by moving the address to ECX and then call ECX which solved the problem with the compiler. But... the program crashes... Any ideas why? I linked with "ld -e _main hello.obj -lkernel32"

Comment: @Lavonen Have you tried stepping with a debugger? Like OllyDbg/x96dbg and similar? There could be a lot of reasons, including the fact that `MessageBoxA` not being there or `user32.dll` itself. A debugger will rule these basic problems out.

Comment: @Lavonen Adding also that `user32` is most probably subject to ASLR.

Comment: Sorry for such a late answer, I found an example online of my script that works and the problem was a little bigger than what I thought. However, Margaret was completely right concerning my question so I vote it up :)